# Distance measure of ST_ClusterWithin

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgis-2.2

I use SRID 4326(WGS 84).
So what is the measure of distance in `ST_ClusterWithin` . m, km, degree ?
I ask it because in documentation it only says:

```
geometry[] ST_ClusterWithin(geometry set g, float8 distance);
```

while `ST_DWithin` function signature at the same time looks like:

```
boolean ST_DWithin(geometry g1, geometry g2, double precision distance_of_srid);

boolean ST_DWithin(geography gg1, geography gg2, double precision distance_meters);

boolean ST_DWithin(geography gg1, geography gg2, double precision distance_meters, boolean use_spheroid);
```

As i know distance_of_srid for 4326 is degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in degrees if you use SRID 4326. From [here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) :

"--Geometry example - units in planar degrees 4326 is WGS 84 long lat unit=degrees"

Comment: I know this is typical issue in postgis, but just out of curiosity: can you give any real life example where "distance in degrees" makes really sense? Or even give workaround to the issue for global dataset, without significant loss of accuracy?