# How to use ST_ClusterWithin with geography data type and measurement units?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.2

I want to clustering locations use [ST_ClusterWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ClusterWithin.html) function:

```
geometry[] ST_ClusterWithin(geometry set g, float8 distance);
```

My table has column `location` of `geography(Point,4326)` type and I don't understand how to convert it correctly to `geometry` type with ability to specify distance in meters.

The following query can convert `geography` to `geometry` but allow to specify [distance in degrees](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184227/distance-measure-of-st-clusterwithin) that is not acceptable for me:

```
select ST_AsText(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(location::geometry, 0.0001)))
from places
```

So, how to use this function with `geography` data types?

Comment: Do you geographic points cross the date line? Or are they restricted to a small geographic area? One option is always to use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) to convert to some projected coordinate system in meters, along with a cast to geometry. You can always convert back to 4326 and geography afterwards.

Comment: All location points places inside of one city and don't cross any date line. Which SRID related to projected coordinate system should I choose to specify distance in meters?

Comment: Which City :-) Most counties have their coordinate systems which are appropriate to the geoid, determine type of projection, etc, etc, making measurements as accurate as possible in projected meters.

Comment: City: [Russia, Saint-Petersburg](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/421007). Could you please explain how you will find appropriate SRID for this city?

Comment: I don't know much about Russian coordinate systems, but this looks potentially useful: https://epsg.io/3350-5044 Accuracy 3m? In a small area, ie, a city, any distortion should be fairly constant, so for the purposes of cluster distances, the 3m will be a constant (more or less).

Answer (score 3):

The current implementations of `ST_ClusterWithin` and its friends `ST_ClusterIntersecting` and `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` (PostGIS 2.3) are all Cartesian-based, so they won't work on geographic coordinates.  Your best option is to do as @JohnBarça says and transform your coordinates to a planar system in meters.  The "private" function [_ST_BestSRID](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/177276/18189) might be of some use here.  Or for an exploratory first pass, or if your cluster distance is highly approximate, you can do something hackish like `distance_in_meters / 111111.0`.

Comment: I guess the magical number `111111.0` is approximation of `10,000 km/90 degrees`, the distance from pole to equator? This hack is kind of true in north(ing) direction, but in the easting it is accurate only in equator, as around poles you can cover whole 360 degrees easting in one meter, as extreme example. However, specifically for clusters which is never precision science, and if your data is not far north/south, then it may be not that bad approximation. Not many would notice :) But as general hack for st_distance type of calculations this could often give bad results.